# Too many events being triggered on keydown() and Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-audio-api

I am making a synthesizer and what I am trying to accomplish is that a an oscillator will be created once and keypress and then stopped on keyup.

The following is my code.

```js
$(document).on("keydown", e => {
    console.log(e);
    let key = $("div[data-key-id = " + e.keyCode + "]")
    key.addClass('red')
    if (fired) return null;
      fired = true;
      let oscs = playTone($(key[0]).attr("data-frequency"))
      if (!oscs) return null;
      $(document).on('keyup', e => {
          oscs.forEach(osc => {
            osc.stop();
          });
        $('.key').removeClass('red')
        fired = false;
      })
  })
```

Here is the PlayTone function being called.

```js
function playTone(freq) {
  if (!freq) return null;
  let osc = audioCtx.createOscillator();
  let osc2 = audioCtx.createOscillator();
  connectNodes(osc, osc2)
  osc.type = type;
  osc2.type = type2;
  osc.detune.value = detune * 5;
  osc2.detune.value = -detune * 5;
  let number = parseFloat(freq.match(/[\d\.]+/))
  osc.frequency.value = number * octave;
  osc2.frequency.value = number * octave;
  console.log(osc)
  osc.start();
  console.log(osc2)
  osc2.start();
  return [osc,osc2]
}
```

What is happening is that on keydown, the event is being triggered multiple times, this calling playTone multiple times. The amount of oscillators being created is overloaded my CPU and making audio distorted. I need a way to make sure the event is only being fired once. I was trying to achieve this using the fired variable but I am not achieving the results I need.

Comment: You have `$(document).on('keyup'` in your `keydown` event, that is going to create a new and separate keyup event handler each time the keydown event is fired.

Comment: That is a good point thank you. I am still having the same issue though.

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure that you are binding only once to the event:

```js
$(document).unbind('keydown.namespace').bind('keydown.namespace', e => {
    console.log(e);
    let key = $("div[data-key-id = " + e.keyCode + "]")
    key.addClass('red')
    if (fired) return null;
      fired = true;
      let oscs = playTone($(key[0]).attr("data-frequency"))
      if (!oscs) return null;
      $(document).unbind('keyup.namespace').bind('keyup.namespace', e => {
          oscs.forEach(osc => {
            osc.stop();
          });
        $('.key').removeClass('red')
        fired = false;
      })
  })
```